# Terraform - Azure - Extract API from one resource group and import into another resource group

Tags: azure, terraform, apim

I have 5 different APIs in my Dev environment. This environment was built manually.

However, for the subsequent environments like Test, Pre-Prod, etc.. Terraform is being used.

Since I need to create each of the APIs in the subsequent environments, am extracting each of these APIs as a JSON file, making minor tweaks to the API URLs and importing it into the new environments.

The following is the process that am doing right now.

1. Went to Resource groups in Azure
2. Then under API Management service > APIs, clicked on the necessary API
3. Now, clicked on the three dots next to the API that I need and clicked on Export
4. Selected OpenAPI v3 (JSON) format

Now, I'm using the extracted JSON file and using the Terraform code below to add it to the APIM

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "example-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Example API"
  path                = "api/path"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  service_url         = "https://actualURL-of-the-API"

import {
    content_format = "openapi+json"
    content_value  = file("extracted-filename.json")
  }
 
}
```

The issue here is:
Even though the API gets added to the APIM, this doesn't create all the data - like Webservice URL, Backend HTTP(s) endpoint

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you locked into exporting the Json file and importing it on the other environments through Terraform?

The reason I ask is because I attempted something similar but decided to go another route.

Initially I created the API manually in a Dev environment. I then re-created the same API from the ground up using only Terraform. No Json export & import.
I then used that Terraform script to create my other environments.

That allowed me to bypass the import problem altogether since nothing is imported.

I have found that there are downsides to taking this approach; It is much less intuitive to author the API through the Terraform script than through the Azure GUI. This is therefore more time consuming. Especially since my initial API was discarded for the one generated with the Terraform script.
Additionally, I have had problems with Terraform diffs reporting example changes when there are none (I suspect the same problem is to be had when using the import method).

If you are wondering why I decided to go another route? The reason was twofold; Firstly, similar to you, I had trouble with getting the export/import to generate the API that I wanted. Secondly, I prefer not to rely on auto generated files.